# PasteSpecial is pasting multiple times

Tags: vba, excel

**My goal is** : to filter some rows, copy those filtered rows and paste it on another sheet.
I'm doing it twice : the first time, it's working well but the second time, not at all. 
Before my sample of code, you need to know : wsData ---filter--> wsDataUpdated --- filter ---> wsDataUpdated2 .

**The problem is** : the second filter is quite ok, but the paste is like awkward : it's pasting all over the range, I mean : if I have only 2 rows after the filter, and i'm pasting it on the wsDataUpdated2 with the range : ("A1:A100") it'll paste it 50 times !! The awkward part is that it's exactly the same code of my first filter, and on my first filter, even if I have less rows than my range, it's not pasting twice or more... By the way, with some breakpoints, I've seen that the filtered part and the copy part is perfect. The paste part is not okay at all.

Here's a sample of my code :

```
    wsDataUpdated.Range("B4").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, wsCriteria2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    wsDataUpdated.Range("A1:AG10150").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    wsDataUpdated2.Range("A1:AG10150").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    wsDataUpdated2.Range("A1:AG10150").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: This is normal behaviour. Try manual copy-paste of 3 cells into a selection of 9 cells: You'll get three copies. Replace `wsDataUpdated2.Range("A1:AG10150")` with `wsDataUpdated2.Range("A1")`, that should do the trick I think.

Comment: It works. I thought about that but I was like "The first time it works, why not now ?" but it's because the first time, my Sheet is full of zeros.

Comment: I'll add this as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. Try manual copy-paste of 3 cells into a selection of 9 cells: You'll get three copies. Replace

```
wsDataUpdated2.Range("A1:AG10150")
```

with

```
wsDataUpdated2.Range("A1")
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried pasting it only on the first cell?

```
     wsDataUpdated2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```